# Django: issue with relationships between tables

Tags: django, table-relationships

I am creating an enrolment page for a website using Django.  I have three tables: the default User table, a Profile table (to capture additional info) and a Subscription table.

**I have setup the Profile table as follows:**

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

**I have setup the Subscription table as follows:**

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
   subscription_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   profile_id = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When a new user enrols, I create a new Profile and Subscription object for that user in views.py:

```
 #Create a new Profile object for the User
 user_profile = Profile()
 lookup_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
 lookup_user_id = lookup_user.pk
 user_profile.user_id = User.objects.get(pk=lookup_user_id)

 #Create a new Subscription object for the User
 user_subscription = Subscription()
 user_subscription.user_id = User.objects.get(pk=lookup_user_id) 

 lookup_profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=user_profile.user_id)
 lookup_profile_id = lookup_profile.pk
 user_subscription.profile_id = Profile.objects.get(pk=lookup_profile_id)
```

Everything works okay, except I am worried that I am establishing the relationship between the tables in an incorrect manner. When I add the User, Profile and Subscription tables to the Django Admin app, the following appears for each new user profile:

[image: New Profile for a created user]

The following appears for a Subscription object created for a new User:

[image: New Subscription created for a user]

And finally, if I open up a Subscription object, for example, the relationship field (which should be the primary key) just displays the text "Profile object":

[image: Relationship field between User Profile and User Subscription]

I thought that the profile_id field would be an auto-increment number that would appear instead of "Profile object". I am new to Django, and I am worried that I am not establishing the relationship between the Tables correctly.

Your advice is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point of the Profile class? It only stores an id.

Comment: I didn't add the other fields in to the example because it is irrelevant to the issue. It does store other fields.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct autoincrement id field will be used as foreign key.
As for django admin `subscription object` is just defaul representation string of instance you can change it by adding `__str__` method to your models like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.profile_id)
```

With this you will see profile's id instead of `profile object`.